# Update values over time in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables, var

So i have a complexe problem where I have to simulate the change of statu over time (25 years)
my dataframe presented like this:

| age | sex | edu | statu | exp_y | sal | cost | sal_a | cost_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | f | no | em | 2 | 76 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | m | low | unem | 0 | 0 | 0 | 287 | 150 |
| 24 | m | low | unem | 2 | 0 | 0 | 345 | 200 |
| 24 | m | no | em | 10 | 380 | 150 | 0 | 0 |
| 36 | f | hiegh | em | 18 | 684 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
| 42 | f | low | em | 17 | 646 | 245 | 0 | 0 |

change conditions are :

if (statu=="unem" & sal_a>cost_a) then update the values of these variables {statu = "em",age=age+1,  exp_y=exp_y+1, sal=sal_a*(1+0.19*exp_y), cost=cost_a, sal_a=0 and cost_a=0}

if (statu=="em" & sal<cost) so {statu = "unem" ; age=age+1, sal_a=sal, cost_a=cost, exp_y=exp_y, sal=0 and cost=0}

Any ideas pleas,

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# Number of years
  y <- 25

# Create a list
  evol <- list()
  # Make "y" copies of your df
    for (i in 1:y){evol[[i]] <- df}

# At each step (strting in the second element) evaluate the changes
  for (i in 2:y){
  # Logical vector (including the positions of rows to change)
    v.logic  <- evol[[i-1]]$statu=="unem" & evol[[i-1]]$sal_a> evol[[i]]$cost_a
    v.logic2 <- evol[[i-1]]$statu=="em" & evol[[i-1]]$sal<evol[[i-1]]$cost
  # Values to change  
    # Fist condition
      evol[[i]][v.logic,"age"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic,"age"] + 1
      evol[[i]][v.logic,"exp_y"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic,"exp_y"] + 1
      evol[[i]][v.logic,"sal"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic,"sal_a"]*(1+0.19*evol[[i-1]][v.logic,"exp_y"])
      evol[[i]][v.logic, "cost"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic,"cost_a"]
      evol[[i]][v.logic, "sal_a"] <- 0
      evol[[i]][v.logic, "cost_a"] <- 0
    # Second condition
      evol[[i]][v.logic2,"statu"] <- "unem"
      evol[[i]][v.logic2, "age"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic2, "age"] + 1
      evol[[i]][v.logic2, "sal_a"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic2, "sal"]
      evol[[i]][v.logic2, "cost_a"] <- evol[[i-1]][v.logic2, "cost"]
      evol[[i]][v.logic2, "sal"] <- 0
      evol[[i]][v.logic2, "cost"] <- 0
    }
```

It will result on a list where the i-th element represents the table for the i-th year.

Comment: I love how structured your answer was, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this for the first condition

```
for(x in 1:nrow(df)) 
    if(df$statu[x] == "unem" & df$sal_a[x] > df$cost_a[x]) 
    {
    df$statu[x] <-  "em"
    df$age[x] <-  df$age[x] + 1
    df$exp_y[x] <-  df$exp_y[x] +1
    df$sal[x] <- df$sal_a[x]*(1+0.19*df$exp_y[x])
    df$cost[x] <- df$cost_a[x]
    df$sal_a[x] <- 0
    df$cost_a[x] <- 0
    }
```

for the second condition

```
for(x in 1:nrow(df)) 
    if(df$statu[x] == "em" & df$sal[x] < df$cost[x]) 
    {
    df$statu[x] <-  "unem"
    df$age[x] <-  df$age[x] + 1
    df$sal_a[x] <- df$sal[x]
    df$cost_a[x] <- df$cost[x]
    df$exp_y[x] <-  df$exp_y[x]
    df$sal[x] <- 0
    df$cost[x] <- 0
    }
```

- Data

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(27, 21, 25, 24, 36, 42), sex = c("f", 
"m", "m", "m", "f", "f"), edu = c("no", "low", "low", "no", "hiegh", 
"low"), statu = c("unem", "em", "em", "em", "em", "em"), exp_y = c(2, 
1, 3, 10, 18, 17), sal = c(0, 341.53, 541.65, 380, 684, 646), 
    cost = c(0, 150, 200, 150, 300, 245), sal_a = c(76, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), cost_a = c(100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

- Output

```
  age sex   edu statu exp_y    sal cost sal_a cost_a
1  27   f    no  unem     2   0.00    0    76    100
2  21   m   low    em     1 341.53  150     0      0
3  25   m   low    em     3 541.65  200     0      0
4  24   m    no    em    10 380.00  150     0      0
5  36   f hiegh    em    18 684.00  300     0      0
6  42   f   low    em    17 646.00  245     0      0
```